# SWT mouse event listener for disabled controls

Tags: java, swt

Is there any way to listen for mouse events on disabled SWT controls?

Comment: Add mouse listeners to parent of the disabled control. Why you need listeners on disabled controls? Add some code and explain.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: The whole purpose of disabling controls is that they don't receive any events. If you can explain your use-case, we might be able to help.